# Getting Wrong Values in Square Root Guess Formula

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, while-loop

I have a program that ask the user for any number (usually a big number) and stores it in variable "mu". Then it asks the user to enter any 4 significant values. The formula Im trying to create simply takes the 4 significant values and sets them to w,x,y and z. The formula i have is such. mu = w^a * x^b * y^c * z^d. Where a,b,c,d are any of these possible 17 values {{-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1/2, -1/3, -1/4, 0, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. The point of the program is to go through each possible value until each exponent chosen gets the closest value to mu. For example if the user input mu as 200,000 and his inputs for w,x,y,z are 45,180,402,110. Then the programs job is to guess which values to set as the exponents so that 45^a * 180 ^b * 402^c * 110^d is closest to mu or 200,000. Now, im trying to make this work using while loops however my program does not seem to select the correct guesses. (Edited and added another error to compare to but i dont think its correct)

Here is my code so far:

```
double[] Guess = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1.0 / 2, -1 / 3, -1.0 / 4.0, 0,
                1.0 / 4.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 2.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        double er = 0.0;


        out.print("Enter a value for mu:");
        double mu = in.nextDouble();
         double er1 = Math.abs((mu-mu)/mu);
        out.print("Enter your first favorite positive value:");
        double w = in.nextDouble();
        out.print("Enter your second favorite positive value:");
        double x = in.nextDouble();
        out.print("Enter your third favorite positive value:");
        double y = in.nextDouble();
        out.print("Enter your fourth favorite positive value:");
        double z = in.nextDouble();
        while (a < Guess.length) {
            double W = Math.pow(w, Guess[a]);
            while (b < Guess.length) {
                double X = Math.pow(x, Guess[b]);
                while (c < Guess.length) {
                    double Y = Math.pow(y, Guess[c]);
                    while (d < Guess.length) {
                        double Z = Math.pow(z, Guess[d]);
                        er = ((W * X * Y * Z) - mu) / mu; //calculates percent error
                        if (er < 0)
                        {
                         er = er1 * -1;
                        }
                        if (er < er1){
                          er1 = er;
                        }

                        d++;
                    }
                    d = 0;
                    c++;
                }
                c = 0;
                b++;
            }
            b = 0;
            a++;
        }

        out.print("error = " + er);
```

Any one have any insight on what i might be doing wrong or what i may need to add? Thank you for your help!I know my while loops will give me the correct numbers, however i think im not setting my a,b,c,d or my percent error corretly

EDIT = The error value im getting is huge. An enormous value.

Comment: 1) use a for loop rather than a while loop, this will tidy up your code. 2) you need to store your errors and find the answer with the smallest value...

Comment: I think you *may* want to rewrite it with `for` loops. Your logic will be more evident this way.

Comment: Using for loops makes it easier yes, but im asked to re-write using damn while loops. I just cant find my error here.

Comment: Your issue is that you don't _do_ anything in your loop. You are trying to brute force a minimum so you need to _minimise_...

Comment: 0, I believe the error should be `Math.abs()`-ed to be correctly comparable 1, You don't compare the errors, 2, you don't store the value with the minimum error.

Comment: @ppeterka66 Ok I added the comparison to the errors but is my er1 set correctly?

Comment: `er1` is set correctly, but its initial value is zero so you will never find anything smaller than that. Also, whenever you change the value of `er1` (i.e. you found a smaller error), you need to save a copy of the current values of W, X, Y and Z that gave you the new minimum.

Comment: @JoelLee Ok. Is there also anyway that you can write this out so I can see it visually? Only way I can actually learn this stuff is to see it. Thank you.

Comment: I'd rename `e`, `er`, and `er1` so that their purpose is clearer.  And `er = er1 * -1;` isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] Guess = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1.0 / 2, -1 / 3, -1.0 / 4.0, 0, 1.0 / 4.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 2.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] Result = {0,0,0,0};
        double e = 0.0;
        boolean first = true;
        double mu=200000, w=45,x=180,y=402,z=110;

        for(int a = 0; a<Guess.length; a++)
        {
            double W = Math.pow(w,Guess[a]);
            for(int b = 0; b<Guess.length; b++)
            {
                double X = Math.pow(x,Guess[b]);
                for(int c = 0; c<Guess.length; c++)
                {
                    double Y = Math.pow(y, Guess[c]);
                    for(int d = 0; d<Guess.length; d++)
                    {
                        double Z = Math.pow(z, Guess[d]);
                        double temp = Math.abs (W*X*Y*Z - mu);
                        if (first)
                        {
                            e = temp;
                            first = false;
                        }
                        else if (temp<e)
                        {
                            e=temp;
                            Result[0]=a;
                            Result[1]=b;
                            Result[2]=c;
                            Result[3]=d;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Error = " + e*100/mu + '\n');
        System.out.print("a=" + Guess[Result[0]] + "\nb=" + Guess[Result[1]] + "\nc=" + Guess[Result[2]] + "\nd=" + Guess[Result[3]] + '\n');
        }
```